# How to upload files to Google Docs from Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-docs-api

I have working Rails app with authorization from Google and view with documents from Google Docs. How can I make button 'Upload', which upload files from computer to Google Docs? Please help, write teachable code. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

For quick intro and for all the others, check out this documentation that might help: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

This guide explains how to use Ruby on Rails with the Google Data APIs, including samples for the Documents List API:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html